# No Sockets found in /var/run/screen/S-root. when using `screen`

Tags: fedora, gnu-screen

I want to screen on a machine with fedora
the result is:

```
   [root@kitch udp]# screen -ls
    No Sockets found in /var/run/screen/S-root.

    [root@kitch udp]# screen -ls listen_for_exception
    No Sockets found in /var/run/screen/S-root.
```

how to deal with this?
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `-ls`. `-ls` tells `screen` to print out a **l**i**s**t of open screen sesstions, and then quit. It's complaining about "No sockets" because you do not have any screen sessions running. Try:

```
screen -S listen_for_exception
```